# Display formatted HTML text with line break using CSS

Tags: angularjs, html, css

Let's say I have this text:

```
$scope.text = 'This is the first line\nthis is the next line';
```

and i would like to show that in a div tag using agularJs

```
<div>{{text}}</div>
```

How do I show this text formatted **WITH** the line break?
Now it displays like this:

This is the first linethis is the next line

Comment: look for ng-sanitize and $sce.trusAsHtml. Maybe It will help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inline style for clarity

```
<div style="white-space: pre;">{{ text }}</div>
```

Comment: Would also suggest `white-space: pre-wrap` to keep spaces and tabs or `white-space: pre-line` to collapse them.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution would be to use `pre` style inside your div

```
<div style="white-space: pre;">{{ text }}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need some formating in your text, you can use html syntax. If you have no control over your text, you will have to replace the char. Angular can't understand `\n`.

```
$scope.text = 'This is the first line \n this is the next line';
$scope.text =  $scope.text.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>');
```

And then, in your HTML :

```
<div><span ng-bind-html="text"></span></div>
```

Comment: OK, but I have no control over the text. I would like to do this without re-formatting to HTML.

Comment: Then you will have to replace, you can't use `\n` directly.

Comment: Topic is really "Display formatted HTML text with line break using CSS"

Comment: @MikkoViitala And it's also tag angularJS. There is a way to do it in Angularjs, I just show it.

Comment: Yes, then it would have made more sense as a comment since it's not answer to the question.

Comment: To be fair to Mr @Apédémak. I added the "using CSS" about a minute after the first post.